# ScrollView not scrolling in Nativescript-Vue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

I have a problem with a scrollable view. I have a scrollable list of items which does not scroll. I wrap a vertical stacklayout with scrollview, and inside the stacllayout I placed a gridlayout with v-for loop.

This is my code:

```
<template>
<ScrollView android:clipToPadding="false" orientation="vertical" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:rgb(245,245,245);">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:10px;"> 
        <GridLayout columns="auto,*" rows="auto,auto,auto" v-for="comment in 6" :key="comment" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin:5px 0px; padding:20px; background-color:white;" >
            <Image row="0" col="0" src="~/assets/images/menu-2.jpg" loadMode="async" stretch="fill" style="width:55px; height:55px;  border-radius:50%; margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;"></Image>
            <StackLayout row="0" col="1" orientation="horizontal" style="width:100%; height:20px; ">
                <Label :text="'fa-star' | fonticon" class="fa" v-for="star in 5" fontSize="12" :key="star" style="color:yellow; vertical-align:center;"></Label>
                <Label text="hace 3 horas" class="fa c_grey" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px; vertcal-align:center;"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label row="1" col="1" class="c_normal fs_smaller" textWrap="true" style="margin:0;" lineHeight="0" text="I have not tried iOS yet. This may not be the best approach either. I am attempting to make a crop-box. In the view the user will see an image under the clip-path that they will position. I am not actually cropping the image. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to state width / height 100% on each component. By setting height 100% on the StackLayout, you restrict the StackLayout from growing beyond screen bounds, so it's not scrollable.

```
<template>
<ScrollView android:clipToPadding="false" orientation="vertical" style="background-color:rgb(245,245,245);">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" style="padding:10px;"> 
        <GridLayout columns="auto,*" rows="auto,auto,auto" v-for="comment in 6" :key="comment" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin:5px 0px; padding:20px; background-color:white;" >
            <Image row="0" col="0" src="~/assets/images/menu-2.jpg" loadMode="async" stretch="fill" style="width:55px; height:55px;  border-radius:50%; margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;"></Image>
            <StackLayout row="0" col="1" orientation="horizontal" style="width:100%; height:20px; ">
                <Label :text="'fa-star' | fonticon" class="fa" v-for="star in 5" fontSize="12" :key="star" style="color:yellow; vertical-align:center;"></Label>
                <Label text="hace 3 horas" class="fa c_grey" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px; vertcal-align:center;"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label row="1" col="1" class="c_normal fs_smaller" textWrap="true" style="margin:0;" lineHeight="0" text="I have not tried iOS yet. This may not be the best approach either. I am attempting to make a crop-box. In the view the user will see an image under the clip-path that they will position. I am not actually cropping the image. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</template>
```

**Note:** It's recommended to use ListView over v-for to render list of items for better performance.